# Custom X axis in core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have this X axis in my sample project on Core Plot and I wonder how I can customise it a little bit. As you can see it currently has only 3 values on the X axis:
[image]

But the values of the two plots I have (the black and grey ones) go far beyond the number of points in the X axis (29 against 3 points). Because of the fact that I have 3 points, only 3 values for each plot are shown.
I would like to keep displaying the remaining 3 points on the axis but accommodate all my 29 events for my plots (they could be displayed in the middle of 1 and 2 point).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the length of the `xRange` of the plot space. The value needed depends on the plot data.